# Issue about the Cauchy problem of separable variables differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

Consider the Cauchy problem
$$\begin{cases}x'(t)=f(x) \\ x(0)=x_0\end{cases}$$
with $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and $f:I\subseteq\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

If $f(x_0)=0$, then $x(t)=x_0$ is the solution of the equation. If $f(x_0)\neq 0$, **then $f(x(t))\neq 0 \, \forall t$ in the maximal interval of definition of the solution, because the solution is unique.**

I don't understand the bold part: supposing that $\exists t_1$ such that $f(x(t_1))=0$, what is the contradiction? I was thinking that, defining $x(t_1):=x_1$, if $x_1$ is a zero of $f$, then $x(t)=x_1$ can be another solution of the problem, which contradicts the unicity, but this is not true since $x(0)=x_1\neq x_0$, so $x(t)=x_1$ is not a solution of the problem. What am I missing?

Comment: You just showed the contradiction. You assumed there was a solution with $f(x(t_1))=0$ and showed that such a solution cannot be a solution with $x(0) = x_0$.

Comment: @whpowell96 I don't understand where is the contradiction: $x(t)=x_1$ is not a solution of the Cauchy problem with initial condition $x(0)=x_0$, but this does not prove that a solution with $f(x(t_1))=0$ and $x(0)=x_0$ does not exists. For example, why a nonconstant function $x$ with $x(0)=x_0$ and $t_1$ as a stationary point (so $x'(t_1)=0$) cannot exists in this context?

Comment: If $f(x(t_1))=0$ and $x_1 = x(t_1)$, then $x_1$ is a constant solution both forwards and backwards in time in its interval of existence. If $x(t)$ is constant with value $x_1$, then $x(0) = x_1\neq x_0$.

Comment: Basically, if a constant function is a solution with value $x_1$, then all solutions taking on that value must be constant by uniqueness

Comment: @whpowell96 The problem is that it seems to me that $x(t)=x_1$ is not a solution in the first place. I mean, it's a solution of the differential equation itself, but is not a solution of the given Cauchy problem since it doesn't match the initial condition, and since the uniqueness is relative to the Cauchy problem, the fact that is a solution of the differential equation but not of the Cauchy problem doesn't seems a contradiction to me.

Comment: It is a solution of a different Cauchy problem (with $x(0) = x_1\neq x_0$) and is hence not a solution of the Cauchy problem with $x(0) = x_0$ by uniqueness.

Comment: @whpowell96 Sorry, I still don't understand. Why the fact that $x_1$ is not a solution of the given Cauchy problem implies that cannot exist a solution with $x'(t_1)=0$ at all? How does the fact that $x_1$ is a solution of the differential equation above allow me to use the uniqueness property, which is relative to the Cauchy problem and not the equation itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x(t_1)=x_1$ and $f(x_1)=0$, then as you found also $\bar x(t)\equiv x_1$ is a solution.

Now you have the situation that both $x$ and $\bar x$ solve the Cauchy problem with initial condition $x(t_1)=x_1$. This is impossible. So you have to backtrack to the last assumption. Thus $x(t_1)=x_1$ or $\dot x(t_1)=f(x(t_1))=0$ is not possible. And if you want to force this, then $x(0)=x_0$ is not possible, but that was the problem to solve, so we can not throw out this condition.